Pymysql badly formats parameters
I just moved to a new venv with pymysql version upgraded from v1.1.0 to v1.1.1 and I now have SQL errors when parameters are formatted by the Cursor.execute function

Here is an example
client_id = float(2)
params = (client_id)
print(f"Parameters :\n\t{params}")
try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = %s", params)
except:
    print("EXCEPTION")
print(f"Query :\n\t{cursor._executed}")

And here is the executed query
Parameters :
    (2.0)
Query : 
    SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = 2.0e0

It's not an issue if I retrieve data, however when I'm inserting or updating data, it fails
client_id = float(2)
balance = np.float64(1000)
params = (client_id, balance)
print(f"Parameters :\n\t{params}")
try:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE client_balances SET balance = %s WHERE client_id = %s", params)
except:
    print("EXCEPTION")
print(f"Query :\n\t{cursor._executed}")

Output :
Parameters : 
    (2.0, np.float64(1000.0))
EXCEPTION
Query : 
    UPDATE client_balances SET balance = np.float64(1000)e0 WHERE client_id = 2.0e0

If I check the exception I get the following error
ProgrammingError - (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'e0, balance = np.float64(1000)e0, WHERE client_id = 2.0e0' at line 1")


I realized that if I manually force parameters formatting as string, it does work.
client_id = float(2)
balance = np.float64(1000)
params = (client_id, balance)
print(f"Parameters :\n\t{params}")

refactored_params = []
for param in params:
    refactored_params.append(str(param))

try:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE client_balances SET balance = %s WHERE client_id = %s", refactored_params)
except:
    print("EXCEPTION")
print(f"Query :\n\t{cursor._executed}")

Output :
Parameters : 
    (2.0, np.float64(1000.0))
Query : 
    UPDATE client_balances SET balance = '1000' WHERE client_id = '2.0'


So I could implement a fix where I manually convert the parameters before calling execute, but since I had no issue before changing my venv I'd like to understand if I'm doing something wrong instead of making a workaround that is not really efficient.
Moreover I can't believe that pymysql can't correctly convert parameters into a query, so I think I'm certainly doing something wrong.
Any thoughts about this issue ? Should I either manually force string conversion or change the implementation ?

While I review the rest of your question, note that params = (client_id) does not create a tuple. The brackets are ignored

Ok, so I'm less sure you should be able to pass numpy types to a DB engine because they are special types (web frameworks won't really work with them either for e.g. plotting). But the python float representation looks like a bug if I'm honest

Are you sure that this behaviour changed between the two versions and nothing else changed?

FWIW, I am unable to reproduce your error with either PyMySQL 1.1.0 or PyMySQL 1.1.1. Also, what does this have to do with SQLAlchemy?

"np.float64(1000.0)" is a variable in Python and it won't be accepted by MySQL.
Parameters : 
  (2.0, np.float64(1000.0))
Maybe, it should be:
  (2.0, 1000.0)

I'm not sure. It might be a problem with "numpy".

It is not the fact that it's a "variable", it's a "type" because numpy wraps C types. I'm not sure what this answer adds and it doesn't address that, apparently, this behaviour changed between versions
